# Python SQLite delete rows IN

Tags: python, sqlite

It's a similar problem to others out there but no body has clearly explained how to correct this:

***process.py***

```
import sqlite3  # version 2.6.0

connection = sqlite3.connect('./db.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()
count_before = cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_data;').fetchall()[0][0]
print('{} rows in {}'.format(count_before, table_name))

query = 'DELETE FROM r_data WHERE pk IN (501, 668);'
print('Deleted ', cursor.execute(query).rowcount, 'rows')

count_after = cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM r_data;').fetchall()[0][0]
print('{} rows in {}'.format(count_after, table_name))
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

output:

```
$ python process.py 
824 rows
822 rows
$ python process.py 
824 rows
822 rows
```

I know that the SQL queries are fine because I can run them successfully through other sqlite "clients" such as the firefox sqlite manager plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Right, need to commit on connection:

```
cursor.close()
connection.commit()   # <<<<< !!
connection.close()
```